Simple way with vanilla JS to toggle css style (not class)?
I know Javascript allows you to toggle a class on click, like:
target.addEventListener('click', function() {
   container.classList.toggle('hidden');
})

I'm wondering if it's possible to easily toggle a style in a similar way without listening to whether or not a user clicks to close/clicks out of the target element?
Like instead of just setting a style like:
container.style.bottom = rect_height
have it easily set/removed on the same click event???
From what I can tell, the answer is no, but was curious if anyone knew something I didn't!
I can't put it into a class in a stylesheet to toggle because the rect_height is calculated by js

You would need a listener event or some type of event to trigger the switch; you can set style instead of class and in your case change the style dynamically each click.

Can you be clear on when you would want this toggle to occur?   You state without listening [for] a click but then also on the same click event.

@fdomn-m Sorry if that's unclear, i meant without listening for a separate click-out of the target. So the same click event would both add or remove style if it's missing/exists
